# Obj-C, how should I pass several app delegate properties into an cocoa touch framework method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, frameworks, protocols

How should I pass several app delegate properties into a cocoa touch framework method?

I'm thinking of using a protocol with required properties and use the type of protocol as my method argument type.

Obviously the framework needs to know what properties exist.

However, it doesn't feel right to pass the app delegate into a method like this.

PS. I know a good question shouldn't include "should" but I think it's relevant in this case.

Comment: Which Cocoa Touch framework method?

Comment: My own method in my own framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't pass the `AppDelegate` into your own custom code. That creates a coupling that is far far too tight.

Much better to at the right point unpack the properties you need, pack those into a struct and pass that into your framework.

Comment: The thing is there’s several properties required by a lot of small functions which get called a lot

Comment: I don't see how that really changes things unless you give me more details.

Comment: I’m trying to pass a model of several properties into framework functions. But obviously the framework needs to know what these properties are. My app then needs to conform to this structure.